# Selenium WebDriver issue with By.cssSelector

Tags: firefox, selenium, css-selectors, webdriver

I have an element whose html is like :

```
<div class="gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text">Announcements</div>
```

I want to check the presence of this element. So I am doing something like :

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text"));
```

But its not able to evaluate the CSSSelector.

Even I tried like :

```
By.cssSelector("gwt-Label.textNoStyle.textNoWrap.titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text")
```

tried with this as well :

```
By.cssSelector("div.textNoWrap.titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text")
```

Note : titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text class is used by only this element in the whole page. So its unique. 
Contains pseudo selector I can not use. 
I want to identify only with css class.

Versions: Selenium 2.9 WebDriver
Firefox 5.0

Comment: What's a sudo selector? Are you sure you're loading the right HTML?

Comment: sudo selector is something which you use along with css selector to identify uniquely. for example if two elements are present like : <div class="gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text">Announcements1</div> and <div class="gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text">Announcements2</div> then you can idcentify them like : .titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text:contains('Announcements1') and .titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text:contains('Announcements2') uniquely with their inner texts.

Comment: I am sorry , it was a spelling mistake, I edited the question.Its pseudo selector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From reading over your post what you should do since that class is unique is just do a `FindElement(By.ClassName("titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text"));`

Also the CssSelector doesn't handle the `contains` keyword it was something that the w3 talked about but never added.

Comment: Any idea why (By.cssSelector(".titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text")) does not work ?

Comment: The cssSelector looks for every class of an element.  So if the element has three classes you have to specify all three classes, which would look like this: By.cssSelector("div[class='gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text']")

Comment: ohh ok.. Thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @CBRRacer I assume that if there is more than one occurence of the said example class name - then the first occurence of the html element is selected and returned as a WebElement object. Is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

When using Webdriver you want to use W3C standard css selectors not sizzle selectors like you may be used to using in jquery.  In your example you would want to use:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class='titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text']"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used css selectors, but this is the xpath selector I would use:

```
"xpath=//div[@class='gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text']"
```

The css selector should then probably be something like

```
"css=div[class='gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text']"
```

Source: http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-remote-control/0.9.2/doc/dotnet/Selenium.html

Comment: css=div[class='gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text'] is not correct. it should be with '.' like gwt-Label.textNoStyle.textNoWrap.titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text . Please refer CSSSelectors here :  http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#selector-syntax

Comment: Okay, that was just a guess based on the Selenium documentation on css selectors. Have you tried using the xpath selector though?

Comment: This css selector that Zoltan mentioned is correct. You don't necessarily need to use '.' all the time. It is just a shortcut - div[class='gwt-Label textNoStyle textNoWrap titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text'] Did you try that?

Comment: @Swagatika the grammar is correct. you should also read http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#matching-attrs

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried following code,

By.cssSelector("div#gwt-Label.textNoStyle.textNoWrap.titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text");

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a wildcard in CSS would be more helpful. Something as follows
`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[class$='titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text']");`

This will look into the class attribute and see what that attribute is ending with. Since your class attribute is ending with "titlePanelGrayDiagonal-Text" string, the added '$' in the css statement will find the element and then you can perform whatever action you're trying to perform.